# How to store JSON response into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm trying to store the JSON response in to variable so that I can process it later, i tried with following but getting null,

```
function go(){
   var jsonObj = getJson(url);
   alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
  }

function getJson(){
    return JSON.parse($.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        global: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
        return data;
        }
    }).responseText);
}
```

mean time i can see the JSON content getting printed on my server console.

**EDIT**

Thannks rid..! that fixed the issue. you solution works fine in IE8, but for Chrome and FireFox still getting 'null' in alert pop-up. i don't think its browser specific fix..?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        global: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
         // do some stufs or assign data to a var
         window.myVar = data;
        }
   });
```

Ajax is asynchronous ,so you need to store the response in a variable in the callback.
in this exemple , window.myVar is a global variable that will contain the response data. You cant access the variable until a response has returned , you'll need to write async code.

Comment: In IE getting the JSON response, but still getting 'null' when tested on FireFox and Chrome browser